# POWERBI: How to make a new table from the intersection of the values ​of a repeated column in two tables

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables with the same columns and I want to make a union between them, in such a way that I get a table in which I only have the products_id that match between them.

Simplifying my case and **omitting the rest of the columns** (customer_id, order_date_id, etc.):

**TABLE 1**:

product_id

1

2

2

2

**TABLE 2**:

product_id

1

1

3

4

The result I want to achieve in this case would be the following:

**TOTAL TABLE**:

product_id

1

1

1

2

2

2

PS: Note that there are more columns, so the UNION() function by itself is not enough.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test this if I understand correctly:

```
    CombinationTable =
VAR Tbl_1 = Table1
VAR Tbl_2 =
    INTERSECT ( Table2, Table1 )
VAR Combination =
    UNION ( Tbl_1, Tbl_2 )
RETURN
    Combination
```

Comment: I just edited my question. I hope I explained it better and easier

Comment: Hello, I updated my solution. Could you please test it ?

Comment: The problem is that I have a huge database and I don't know which IDs match. Therefore, writing product_ID in {1,2} is useless in this case (there will be thousands of values ​​in common). 
Sorry for the inconvenience!!

Comment: Okay, I understood you. I just removed and updated it.

Comment: Thank you!! Tomorrow I'll try tomorrow at work

Comment: @CLT pleasure. You can always ask any questions. In first case, I integrated Table constructor {} to safeguard it against future column changes. Keep that in mind. Stay safe, be well.